# Finding number of values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

What is the best / most efficient way to find the total number of *Values* in a `HashMap`.

I do not mean the [.size()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_size.htm) method as it counts the number of keys. I want the total number of *values* in all the keys.

I want to do so as my key is a `String`, but my value is a `List`.

Comment: Since there is a 1:1 relationship between *key* and *value* in a Java `Map`, perhaps you should explain why the `.size()` method is insufficient.

Comment: But the number of values in a `Map` is equal to the number of keys in this map. What type are these values?

Comment: Please see my edit about, the values are a list

Comment: What is the type of your values ? if your HashMap is <string,string> then it is a 1:1 mapping. If your HashMap is of type say LinkedList then there will be more values than keys

Comment: Then you'll need to iterate the `entrySet` and add together the `size` of the `List`s. A `Map` can contain any kind of `Object`, and a `List` is **one** `Object`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest would be, iterate and add over list sizes.

```
int total = 0;
for (List<Foo> l : map.values()) {
    total += l.size();
}

// here is the total values size
```

Comment: Worked as expected :)

Answer (score 15):

In Java 8, you can also utilize the `Stream` API:

```
int total = map.values()
               .stream()
               .mapToInt(List::size) // or (l -> l.size())
               .sum()
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to repeat the `List<Foo>` type for a `for` variable, as in the pre-Java 8 solution:

```
int total = 0;
for (List<Foo> list : map.values())
{
    total += list.size();
}
System.out.println(total);
```

In addition to that, although not advised, you could also use that value inline without needing a temp variable:

```
System.out.println(map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum());
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Java 8, given a `Map<K, List<V>> map` you could use the Stream API and have:

```
int size = map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

This creates a `Stream` of the values with [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), maps each of them to their size with [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), where the mapper is the method reference `List::size` refering to [`List#size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--), and sum the results with [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--).

Answer (score 4):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), the following will work using [MutableMap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/MutableMap.html).

```
MutableMap<String, List<String>> map = 
        Maps.mutable.of("key1", Lists.mutable.of("a", "b", "c"),
                        "key2", Lists.mutable.of("d", "e", "f", "g"));

long total = map.sumOfInt(List::size);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a map

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can do this by calling the `values()` method and calling `size()` method for all the lists:

```
int total = 0;
Collection<List<Object>> listOfValues = map.values();
for (List<Object> oneList : listOfValues) {
    total += oneList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a `Map<String, List<Something>>`, and you want to count the total number of items in all the `List`s in the `Map`'s values. Java 8 offers a pretty easy way of doing this by streaming the values, mapping them to their `size()` and then just summing them:

```
Map<String, List<Something>> map = ...;
int totalSize = map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum());
```

Comment: @MuddassirRahman yes, it work with any `Collection`. Just change the method reference `List::size` to `Collection::size`.

Comment: Works fine but it needs higher version

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Solution {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int total = 0;
        HashMap<String,String> a = new HashMap<String,String>();
        a.put("1.","1");
        a.put("2.","11");
        a.put("3.","21");
        a.put("4.","1211");
        a.put("5.","111221");          
        for (String l : a.values()) {
            total ++;
        }
        System.out.println(total);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Mostafa Hussien. Maybe  you would like to take the site tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour .
About your answer please note that the question specifies that the type of the value is a List.